# Installing ArcGIS Web AppBuilder with Apache web server?

Tags: arcgis-server, installation, apache, arcgis-web-appbuilder

i download ArcGIS Web AppBuilder and installed it with Node.js, its start working on my web browser, the main web page asks for an ip or web address, i have XAMPP & Apache web server installed and running well on my PC, but ArcGIS Web AppBuilder doesn't accept my localhost (127.0.0.1) ip.

Is there any way to make ArcGIS Web AppBuilder works on my PC without internet web site??

Comment: What port is Apache running on?

Comment: Apache running on port :80

Comment: when you say "main web page asks for an ip or web address" are you referring to the config page that the web app builder shows when you first open the WAB in a browser?

Comment: yes this is it the config page